# How to root AVD Android emulator in android studio?

Tags: android, emulation, root

Is there a way to root Android Emulator API 25 8.0/8.1 or greater in Android Studio? I could not find any nub tutorial online. Only for physical device. Please help...

Comment: Don't have one handy, but does `adb root` work?